# Unique stationary distribution (or measure?) of a Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a irreducible, positive recurrent Markov chain. We have a theorem that states that the unique stationary distribution is then given by $$\pi(x)= \frac{1}{E_x[H_x]},$$ 
where $E_x[H_x]$ is the expected hitting time of $x$, when started at $x$, where the hitting time is given by $$H_x:=\inf\{n \geq 1 \colon X_n = x\}.$$

Is this clear that this forms a distribution? Is it clear that it forms a measure at all? How can one see this?

**Context:**

We are proving for a homogeneous irreducible Markov Chain on a countable state space $E$ that the following are equivalent.

1) some state is positive recurrent.

2) all states are positive recurrent.

3) there exists a stationary distribution, given by $\pi(x)= \frac{1}{E_x[H_x]}$

To prove 1) implies 2), we show that $\nu(x):=\frac{1}{E_x[H_x]}$ satisfies $\nu(x)=\sum_{y \in E} \nu(y) r(y,x)$, so that it is stationary measure. From this it follows by induction and by contradiction that all states must be positive recurrent, as the $r$ are positive (using that positive recurrent iff $E_x[H_x]= \infty$, given that it is a recurrent class).

To prove 2) implies 3), we can take the main part from 1) implies 2), and only need to show that the stationary measure can be transformed in a distribution, so we show that it is non-negative, has total mass $<\infty$, such that we can divide through the total mass.

We proved that $\nu(x)$ is a stationary measure based on the average asymptotics that $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n E_y[H_x] \rightarrow \frac{1}{E_x[H_x]} \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$$ for a recurrent state $x$ and also using Fatou's Lemma.

Comment: Clear from what? It's clear after you prove that theorem. Are you asking whether there's an easy way to see that this is a distribution without knowing the connection drawn by that theorem?

Comment: We prove the whole theory behind this, I guess. But at one point, we want to prove that if all states are positive recurrent (in an irreducible Markov Chain), then a stationary distribution exists. Then we state that a stationary distribution is given by $\frac{\pi(x)}{\sum_x \pi(x)}$, and this confuses me, as I thought we had proved that it is a distribution and so I do not see the need of dividing through it.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following you. Could you spell out more explicitly what's being proved from what and where you see a missing link or a cycle?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I am not sure in which detail I should write it, so please give me a feedback if it is unclear! We have seen several results before this, I can also list them if this helps. thank you a lot and sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I think you forgot irreducibility in the introductory sentence of the context section?

Comment: Yes I did. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: And "To prove 2) implies 1)" must be a typo? Since that implication is trivial.

Comment: yes, you are right. sorry for the mistakes & thank you very much for your help and your patience..

Comment: OK, now I think I understand the context, but now I'm not sure where your question fits in :-) You state in the context section that the question whether this is a distribution was addressed, that you showed its non-negativity and finite mass, and hence its normalizability -- but isn't this then the answer to your question how we know that this is a distribution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25743/discussion-between-joriki-and-user136457).