# Why is the stationary distribution a distribution?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose we have a time-homogeneous, discrete-time, aperiodic, positive recurrent, irreducible Markov chain $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ on a discrete state space $E$. It is known that its stationary distribution is given by $$\pi(x)=\frac{1}{E_x[H_x]}, \quad x \in E,$$ 
where $H_x$ is the first positive time of visiting $x$ when starting at $x$, i.e.

$$H_x:=\inf\{t \geq 1 \colon X_t= x\}.$$

Why do we know that it is a distribution, so how can one formally see that

$$\sum_{x \in E} \frac{1}{E_x[H_x]}=1?$$

I know about the intuition, but I would really like to see a very formal proof of it or at least a hint how to prove it very formally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique stationary distribution (or measure?) of a Markov Chain](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357692/unique-stationary-distribution-or-measure-of-a-markov-chain)

Comment: Deliberate self-duplicate (plus a huge typo in the new version). Do not do that.

Comment: In the other question I got the answer that it is indeed a stationary distribution and got some intuition, now I know that it is and I am looking for a formal proof. So I do not think that it is a duplicate.

Comment: Really? Now that you know this is a theorem in every course on Markov chains, did you try to check in the textbooks you may have?

Comment: Yes, I did. This is why several days passed since I asked the last question - I spent time looking in some books, but I always see some strange proofs as the "one" we "had" in the lecture. So maybe you could put a link here to a proof?

Comment: At least one example of a "strange proof" you were subjected to should be explained in your question, then we would have something different from "Please copy a chapter of my textbook here for me".

Comment: We proved, as mentioned in the other post, that $\pi$ is a stationary measure using Fatou's Lemma and Fubinis Theorem. In the lecture we argued that this, together with the non-negativity and again applying Fatou's Lemma is enough to show the claim that it is indeed a stationary distribution.